# How to implement a pop (scale up and scale down) animation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I've recently gotten into animating in Jetpack Compose and I have a few questions... Just for context my research consisted of reading the documentation, watching Youtube videos and asking ChatGPT. However, my idea was that the best way to learn is to implement some animations in my projects and to problem solve.

That approach worked for everything in my android app development journey, until now. Beacuse of that I've decided to ask on StackOverflow so here it goes.

In my project there is a counter displayed on screen. The counter is of course a Text() composable which recomposes every time the view model sends it a new number through a stateFlow. The Text() composable is inside a Box() composeable to make it centered, here is the simplified version of it :

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Text(text = myState.number) 
}
```

This part of the code works fine. From here, I want to animate my text in a specific way. I want the text, so the number, to scale up and back down in order to achieve a pop effect. The scaling up should be from 1f to 1.3f max. I want that animation to happen every time the text changes and I want it to have a duration of 200ms.

To make this work I tried many things (animate*asState, AnimatedContent, LaunchedEffect, ...) but all of them seemed to fail.

Any help or a guide in the right direction to solve this would be very appreciated!

PS :

I already made this behaviour in XML and Java, but I cannot replicate it in Jetpack Compose.

Here is the scale up XML animation :

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:toXScale="1.314"
    android:toYScale="1.314"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="100"

    >
</scale>
```

And the scale down animation :

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="1.314"
    android:fromYScale="1.314"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="100"

    >
</scale>
```

EDIT 1 :

Here is an example of the animation :
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms6Nb.gif)

This the effect I want to achieve, but not the exact animation. As I stated before, I only want my text to scale up and back down every time it changes (to achieve a pop effect), I don't want my text to scale up and down continuously like shown in the example.

Another example of the effect I want to achieve is this :
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBz0s.gif)

So here you can see the same thing, text scaling up and back down. I want this to happen every time my text changes, but not this slow like shown in the example, it has to be faster to produce a "pop" effect.

Comment: Could you please provide some example of this animation? From you describe i imagine something like animation provided by [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers#animatedcontent). Maybe i wrong)